# Is it possible to wire a DPDT switch so that each position creates an output? (3 outputs)

Tags: switches, dpdt

I am controlling three LEDs, and need to be able to toggle between them individually with a switch. Is this achievable with a DPDT switch? I'm not sure where I can find a switch that has one input and three possible outputs.

Comment: The search term is "SP3T" for Single Pole, Triple-Throw -- or "ON-ON-ON".  For example https://www.mouser.com/Electromechanical/Switches/Toggle-Switches/_/N-5g2j?P=1z0z2o4Z1z0z2o3&Keyword=switch+SP3T&Ns=Pricing%7c0&FS=True

Comment: With external components it would be easy. A microcontroller or a logic ic. Or a flip flop circuit. But just buying the right switch would be easier.

Comment: I keep toggle switches on hand with center-off and spring-return-to-center options. These are common for reversible motors with an OFF position.

Comment: Callum, I like @VTNCaGNtdDVNalUy 's answer but it also requires some added circuit components to make it work. Some more crafty answers might require some knowledge of your individual LEDs (if they are different, that difference can sometimes be used to advantage.) But I've another question for you. Would a rotary switch work for you? Do you know about these?

Comment: How many ON-OFF states do we have? If all are OFF that is 4 states. Not possible with 3 position toggle. Rotary switch is best. Is single pole 23 position ok?

Comment: "buying the right switch would be easier. " really? my experiance is that on-off-on 3 position toggle and rocker switches are readily available, while I don't think I have ever seen such a switch with contacts for all 3 positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using an ON-OFF-ON switch like this one:

[image]

one half of the switch in either on position shunts D3 preventing it from illuminating, this wastes about 20mA in the off position the LED lights

the other half selects between the other two LEDs when on

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH2pDS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: D3 won't turn on.   Always +5V on both sides.   Well maybe as you switch it

Comment: use a on-off-on DPDT switch  circuitlab doesn't haver that in it's library so you'll have to immagine

Comment: So the sequence would be red yellow green, but no OFF state without another switch. OP said nothing about an off state.

Answer (score 1):

A SP3T slide switch (single pole triple throw) may be used.

It may be identified by a higher pitch between one terminal and common.

[image]

Should SP3T not be available DP3T may be used.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Jasen has a very simple way of doing it that is probably what you should use.

Just for interest, here is a circuit that (at the cost of a few more parts) uses less power because it does not depend on shorting out an LED in two of the positions, so it's better suited for battery power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc5OsD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do it with a single pole ON-OFF-ON switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkmkPF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It relies on the center 'OFF' position LED D1 needing more voltage to turn it on than the others. When either of the 'ON' LEDs is switched in its lower voltage drop robs current from the 'OFF' LED.

D4 increases the voltage required to turn on the 'OFF' LED, and R2 ensures enough current passes through D4 to get a good voltage drop (without it D1 may glow weakly when one of the others is switched on).

Depending on the LEDs used, D4 and R2 may not be required. If D1 is Blue or White and the others are Red, Green, or Yellow then their voltage differences alone may be enough. If D1 is Green or Yellow and one of the others is Blue or White then 2 diodes in series may be required to get sufficient voltage drop.

Each LED is lit through R1, so the circuit is efficient. However the LED currents are not individually adjustable, which may be a problem for different colored LEDs with greatly different brightnesses.